# Grep every word from a file starting a pattern

Tags: bash, grep

So I have a file let's call "page.html". Within this file, there's some links/file paths I want to extract. I've been working in BASH trying to get this right but can't seem to do it. The words/links/paths I want to grab all start with "/funny/hello/there/". The goal is for all these words to go to the terminal so I can use them.

This is kinda what I've tried so far, with no luck:

```
grep -E '^/funny/hello/there/` page.html
```

and

```
grep -Po '/funny/hello/there/.*?` page.html
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Here is sample data from the file:

```
`<td data-title="Blah"  class="Blah" >
                                                                                                                                        <a href="/funny/hello/there/fkljaskdjfl" title="This here">fdsksldjfah</a>
                                                                                            </td>`
```

My output gives me all the different line that look like this:

`<a href="/funny/hello/there/fkljaskdjfl" title="This here">fdsksldjfah</a>`

The "/fkljaskdjfl" are all something different though.

What I want the output to look like:

```
/funny/hello/there/fkljaskdjfl
/funny/hello/there/kfjasdflas
/funny/hello/there/kdfhakjasa
```

Comment: Can you show sample data from input file and your expected output.

Comment: @anubhava See update

Comment: @anubhava Think you can help me? I'm really stuck

Comment: Try: `grep -o "/funny/hello/there/[^'\"[:blank:]]*" page.html`

Comment: @anubhava Worked perfectly! You are the bomb!

Comment: Cool, posted it as as answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `grep` command:

```
grep -o "/funny/hello/there/[^'\"[:blank:]]*" page.html
```

However one should avid parsing HTML using `shell` utilities and use dedicated HTML dom parsers instead.